# How to deserialize multiple json fields into single object with kotlinx serialization

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

Consider the following json structure representing a basic check-in information

```
{
  "id": "53481198005",
  "date": "1995-01-01 00:00:00",
  "latitude": "50.765391",
  "longitude": "60.765391"
}
```

During deserialization, I want to consume latitude and longitude and create a single object called Location. In other words, I want to parse this json with POJO classes similar to:

```
@Serializable
data class CheckInRecord(val id: String, val date: String, val location: Location)

@Serializable
data class Location(val latitude: String, val longitude: String)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just let them deserialize into `lat` and `long`, and then provide a `location` property that composes a value from the `lat` and `long` properties?  To the world outside `CheckInRecord` it would be indistinguishable.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense and simple, works for my case but I guess Location is a good example from domain perspective and in a real world scenario CheckInRecord can be huge. Here it just contains 3-4 attributes but we may encounter a larger POJO where you may want to clean the mess for the CheckInRecord class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this with the [surrogate serializer pattern](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#composite-serializer-via-surrogatehttps://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#composite-serializer-via-surrogate), which is in exactly the same fashion as in the [question I answered earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77887617/how-can-i-serialize-a-calculated-property/77888080#77888080), but in reverse (as that was about encoding rather than decoding).

To apply the pattern, you start off writing a serializable surrrogate object to match the JSON you want:

```
@Serializable
class CheckInRecordSurrogate(
    private val id: String,
    private val date: String,
    private val latitude: String,
    private val longitude: String
) {
    companion object {
        fun fromCheckInRecord(checkInRecord: CheckInRecord) = with(checkInRecord) {
            CheckInRecordSurrogate(id, date, location.latitude, location.longitude)
        }
    }

    fun toCheckInRecord() = CheckInRecord(id, date, Location(latitude, longitude))
}
```

This gives you the tools to implement the `KSerializer` interface for your target class `CheckInRecord` by 'plugging in the gaps' to translate the surrogate to your desired end object (and back, for completeness):

```
class CheckInRecordSerializer : KSerializer<CheckInRecord> {
    private val surrogateSerializer get() =  CheckInRecordSurrogate.serializer()
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor get() = surrogateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = surrogateSerializer.deserialize(decoder).toCheckInRecord()

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: CheckInRecord) {
        surrogateSerializer.serialize(encoder, CheckInRecordSurrogate.fromCheckInRecord(value))
    }
}
```

Finally, you must tell the framework to use your new serializer on `CheckInRecord` (note we don't even need to make `Location` serializable with this approach):

```
@Serializable(with = CheckInRecordSerializer::class)
data class CheckInRecord(val id: String, val date: String, val location: Location)
```

Now we can try it all out:

```
println(
    Json.decodeFromString<CheckInRecord>("""
        {
             "id": "53481198005",
             "date": "1995-01-01 00:00:00",
             "latitude": "50.765391",
             "longitude": "60.765391"
        }
     """)
)
```

Which prints what we expect, showing `CheckInRecord` was successfully instantiated:

```
CheckInRecord(id=53481198005, date=1995-01-01 00:00:00, location=Location(latitude=50.765391, longitude=60.765391))
```